# CursorAdapter.swapCursor not refreshing the first time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a **ListActivity** and use a **CursorLoader** to load the data which is stored in a ContentProvider. I use a custom class extending **CursorAdapter** to display the list items. In the LoaderCallbacks *onLoadFinished* I have the following:

```java
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor newCursor) {
   cursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
}
```

I have a custom layout for the ListActivity which includes a TextView with `android:id="@android:id/empty"`.

The problem is that when I open the application for the first time calling `swapCursor`does not refresh the ListView even though there is data to show in the ContentProvider. When I add a new item to the ListView, the list is refreshed properly. However, if I comment out the TextView, which displays a simple text when no data is available, the application works as expected. The swapCursor call *automagically* updates the ListView accordingly.

Any thoughts on why this occurs or if there is a proper way to do this since I believe calling notifyDataSetChanged won't do the work as the refreshing fails on a very particular case?

Comment: You should use `changeCursor` if the old cursor is not used anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having this problem because `ListActivity` automatically sets the empty view (if available) to your `ListView`.

I'd suggest you try one of these:

1. Extend activity and after `swapCursor` call

   ```
   listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
   ```
2. Make the empty view gone: `android:visibility="gone"` and after `swapCursor` call

   ```
   findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   ```
3. @onCreate call `listView.setEmptyView(null)` and after `swapCursor` call

   ```
   listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
   ```

Not sure about all of them, but one of em will certainly work :)